# How to open a new window not in the same new window?

Tags: c#, javascript

How to open a new window not in the same new window?

The following code can open a new window However after pressing button again
the content will be replaced. How to open the next or next next content in a new window not in the same new window

```
string strPop = "<script language='javascript'>" +
            "window.open('viewpage.aspx?type=3&start=" + txtStartDate.Text + "&end=" + txtEndDate.Text + "','Report');" +
            "</script>";
            Page.RegisterStartupScript("Pop", strPop);
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the window name '`Report`' with '`_blank`' or generate a unique window name instead of the static '`Report`' name.

Answer (score 0):

Always give the new windows new names and they'll open in separate windows